# Can macOS (Catalina) match a Brazilian Portuguese Windows keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

The Windows Portuguese keyboard has a different layout than the Apple Portuguese keyboard:

Here's the Windows version:
[image]

Here's the Apple's version:
[image]

I don't want to buy a new keyboard or learn a new keyboard layout (right now I am forced to use Windows because I can't use my keyboard on MacOS).

Can I remap macOS software to respect the Windows keyboard layout?

Comment: Is the windows keyboard a Bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: The layouts are very similar...

Comment: @jmh I think 7 keys at least need remapping to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom layout to remap the various character keys to match what you want with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Comment: I ended up using this solution. If anyone would like to have my .keylayout file here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PQiOnfmswjEsBfWF1lK97Sw5tCpybvTt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes. Thanks for that link!  Will add this fix to my own blog on such issues.  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

A free solution you could try is [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). It allows you to remap keys to other keys.

> ## Core features
>
> - **Simple Modifications**: Change normal keys to other keys.
> - **Complex Modifications**: Change keys by complex rules.
> - Change a key to combination of modifiers. (e.g. change capslock to control+command)
>
>   - Change modifiers+key to key. (e.g. change control+m to return)
>   - Send key events if a key is pressed alone.
>   - Send key events if keys are pressed simultaneously.
>   - Mouse keys.
>   - etc.
> - **Function Keys**: Change f1-f12 keys to media controls.
> - **Devices**: Apply modifications to specified keyboards only.
> - **Profiles**: Support multiple profiles.
> - **Modifier Flag Sync**: Synchronize modifier flags across all connected keyboards.
> - **Secure Keyboard Entry Support**: Work well on Secure Keyboard Entry environment such as a password prompt, terminal with Secure Keyboard Entry, etc.

[image]

I have used it to bring an old Nostromo Speedpad2 back to life. And it's FREE!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply connect your keyboard.

When you connect it, whether wirelessly or via USB cable, it will go through the process of identifying the keyboard type.

There are a couple of conventions you have to remember...

- Control = Control
- Option = Alt
- Command = windows key

Comment: This does not address any questions about remapping the keys which produce different outputs on the two layouts.

Comment: @tom the question about remapping wasn’t there when I initially answered. I’ll add it in

Answer (score 0):

If your windows keyboard is a Bluetooth keyboard just set it close to your mac and go to the Bluetooth menu bar icon and click.  It will list the devices in range of your computer. Click on your keyboard from the pull-down menu and then just click connect.  Give it a few seconds to connect and you should be good to go.

Comment: This does not address any questions about remapping the keys which produce different outputs on the two layouts

Comment: if OP gets the keyboard to work there is no need for the key remapping.

Comment: How do you figure that?  Without a custom layout, half a dozen keys will produce different characters than what his fingers are trained to expect.